# pdo query not running

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i can't seem to figure out why this query isn't running

```
if ( $productName && $productDescription && $productPrice ) {
// SQL
// UPDATE `prostud_tristurion`.`products` SET `product_title` = 'ajax test', `product_description` = 'Was certainty remaining engrossed applauded sir how discovery.', `product_price` = '524' WHERE `products`.`product_id` = 10;
try {

    $query = "update products set product_title = :pName, product_description = :pDescription, product_price = :pPrice, where product_id = :pid";
    //prepare query for excecution
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

    //bind the parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pName', $productName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pDescription', $productDescription);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pPrice', $productPrice);
    // echo "$productPrice / $productDescription / $productName / $id\n $stmt";
    var_dump($_POST);
    // Execute the query
    if ($stmt->execute() ) {
        echo "Record was updated.";
    } else {
        die('Unable to update record.');
    }

}catch(PDOException $exception){ //to handle error
    echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
}
```

all i get is **Unable to update record.**

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

is looking good

Comment: `product_price = :pPrice,` <= it's the comma. *"all i get is Unable to update record."* You're not checking for errors. *Naughty naughty*. `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an errant comma at `product_price = :pPrice, where`

If your code reaches the `die` statement then you have exceptions turned off (not recommended) but you can get the error message from the database (to log or echo) with `$stmt->errorInfo()`

Comment: The downvote definitely needs explaining.

Comment: Good catch! I would also add that to be sure that the record was really updated , one should check for affected rows via `rowCount()`

Comment: thank you :) / i've been working all night ...

Comment: who downvoted this? that superfluous comma caused the error on the preparation making this answer valid and does not merit the downvote